# I want to do an animation, but just one time, not to be on a loop

Tags: javascript, css

I want to do an animation, but just one time, not to be on a loop.

In this example, when the animation reach the purple color I want it to stop. Not to start all over.

```css
@keyframes load {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.e {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.one {
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite;
  animation: load 5s infinite;
}
.two {
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite 1s;
  animation: load 5s infinite 1s;
}
.three {
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite 2s;
  animation: load 5s infinite 2s;
}
.four {
  background: orange;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite 3s;
  animation: load 5s infinite 3s;
}
.five {
  background: purple;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite 4s;
  animation: load 5s infinite 4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="e one"></div>
<div class="e two"></div>
<div class="e three"></div>
<div class="e four"></div>
<div class="e five"></div>
```

Comment: FYI, [you don't need vendor prefixes for `animation`](https://caniuse.com/css-animation). Even ancient IE handles it without.

Comment: replaced infinite with forwards